# How to add a timer to a clicking game program

Tags: python

So I am currently trying to make a clicking game for a final project but I have no clue how to make the timer go during the game and stop the game once the timer is up.

I've tried to implement a sleep timer into the program like

```
import time

seconds = 60

for i in range(seconds):
    print(str(seconds - i) + " seconds remain")
    time.sleep(1)
```

but it doesn't go simultaneously with the clicking game.  The code I made for the clicking game is:

```
def display(x,y):
    global numClicks
    clear()
    numClicks +=1
    drawString("Number of clicks: "+str(numClicks),
100,150,"Arial",28,"normal")
    update()

numClicks = 0
beginGrfx(800,500)
onscreenclick(display)
endGrfx()
```

The clicking game works and the timer starts at 60 seconds but it doesn't count down after that.  Is there a different timer code I should be using or what?

Comment: I would recommend you using threads. You can checkout this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/34562473/11335072

Answer (score 0):

From that same module, you can use [`time.time()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html) method to get the current time. And then assuming you know how long the timer will run for, you can add to that amount and have a while loop run the program until that time is up. E.g:

```
start_time = time.time()
end_time = start_time + 10 # ten second timer

while time.time() < end_time:
    # run game logic...
```